# How do I test a YAML form for problem reporting on a GitHub project page before I install it?

Tags: github, yaml

I'm a Git/GitHub beginner and don't know YAML (yet).

I found [this](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/syntax-for-issue-forms) about making an issue reporting form, but I'm sure I won't get it right the first try, so I need a way to run it as a test without inflicting it on the live project.

I searched briefly and didn't see any application that would open and render YAML the way I would use a browser for HTML.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally create a new project or repo to test on and when happy, simply copy paste the final result to the project you want to have these enabled for real.